# Remove elements from hashset of integer VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

how do i make this work, does not work like a normal list.
I have to delete from the list, which contains i.

if my list contains (`2,4,3,13,21,14,15,30`)

I want to delete the first 6 elemtent.

```
  Public randomcards As New HashSet(Of Integer)

        For i As Integer = 0 To 5
          randomcards.remove(i)
        Next
```

so after the operation, my list will become 15,30 with only 2 element.

Unfortunately, this is not a normal list and I would need a little help

Comment: From the documentation for [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1), "A HashSet<T> collection is not sorted and cannot contain duplicate elements. If order or element duplication is more important than performance for your application, consider using the List<T> class together with the Sort method." There is no "first" element of a HashSet.

Comment: However, you could go via an IEnumerable, like `randomcards = randomcards.Skip(6).ToHashSet()`, but you shouldn't really rely on it always giving the result you intend.

Comment: That is not a sensible operation on a hashset.  If you want an ordered *list* then you need a List(Of Integer)

Comment: `HashSet(Of T)` is based on the [mathematical concept of a set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)). A set either contains a specific element or it does not. The elements are not ordered and have no index or position.

Comment: I can tell you how to delete any 6 elements.. will that suffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather tedious because you can't refer to items in a HashSet by index. Keep in mind you can't alter any collection in a For Each by removing an element.

1. Create a HashSet.
2. Create a list.
3. Add the first 6 elements of the HashSet to the list.
4. Loop through the list checking if the item in the list is in the HashSet. If True remove it.

   ```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       Dim hs As New HashSet(Of Integer) From {2, 4, 3, 13, 21, 14, 15, 30}
       Dim lst As New List(Of Integer)
       Dim counter As Integer
       For Each i In hs
           If counter < 6 Then
               lst.Add(i)
           Else
               Exit For
           End If
           counter += 1
       Next
       For Each i In lst
           If hs.Contains(i) Then
               hs.Remove(i)
           End If
       Next
       MessageBox.Show(hs.Count.ToString)
       For Each i In hs
           Debug.Print(i.ToString)
       Next
   End Sub
   ```

```
@Calaf's answer look superior.
```

Answer (score 2):

By definition, an `HashSet` collection is **not sorted** (see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-6.0#remarks)), so

> I want to delete the first 6 element

makes no sense.

If you know which element you want to remove (for example the number 14), use

```
randomcards.Remove(14)
```

By the same principle, if you want to remove 6 randomic integer (compliance with the insertion order is not guaranteed!), you can do something like this:

```
Dim fakeList As Integer() = randomcards.ToArray()
For i As Integer = 0 To 5
    randomcards.Remove(fakeList(i))
Next
```

Comment: I think the OP needs an *ordered* entity, not a *sorted* entity. (It just happens that iterating over a HashSet appears to have an order, but there is no guarantee that two successive iterations over the values will return the values in the same order.)

Comment: Conceptually, HashSets are unordered and unsorted collections. Using a HashSet instead of a LinkedList or similar is wrong, as well as unnecessarily convoluted.

Comment: There is a difference between sorted and ordered. I think there was too much visual emphasis on **not sorted** in your answer.

Comment: Ahhh, ok!  I understand what you mean and you are absolutely right!  Mine was a quote from the official documentation (linked in my answer), in the part where it says "A HashSet <T> collection is not sorted and cannot contain duplicate elements ..."